# are there sqlite admin chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-web-store

Is there such thing? I have been searching the net for something similar to phpmyadmin but i cannot seem to find one.

I know there are SQLite managers but I want something that can be used for web development. So something like a chrome extension that will provide an interface where the database can be edited or a greasemonkey script or a bookmarklet or a JS file that can be included.

The Resources tab in the Developer tools of chrome already provides this but is there a way to edit this information just like in phpmyadmin? Or like an "sqlite shell" where queries can be executed?

I find such a tool very useful in developing applications using Databases. Developers would want to be able to edit the database quickly. Or if there aren't any, could you suggest a way to ease this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this in-browser and not as a standalone application?

Comment: Why not just use SQLite?

Comment: How can I access databases created by browsers for websites using a standalone application? If I update it using a standalone application, will the changes also reflect in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing seems to exist after weeks of researching. The best thing that can be done is to access the SQLITE database using a third-party sqlite browser. The database file is in:

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```